# java map of generic processors

Tags: java, generics

After spending quite some time on this I think I can use some help. 
Basically I'm trying to create a set of processors each accepting its own type of object to process. Calling class needs an ability to get a processor based on type of the object and invoke that processor, passing the object.
This is what I have created:

```
abstract class Processor<F> {
    abstract void process(F foo);
}

class AProcessor extends Processor<Integer> {
    public void process(Integer foo){

    }
}

class BProcessor extends Processor<Long> {
    public void process(Long foo){

    }
}
```

Initially I used interface for Processor, it doesn't matter for me really.

Then calling class is like that:

```
public class Test {

    private final Map<Class<?>, Processor<?>> values = new HashMap<Class<?>, Processor<?>>();

    public void main(String[] agrs){
        Test t = new Test();
        t.values.put(Integer.class, new AProcessor());
        t.values.put(Long.class, new BProcessor());

        AProcessor ap = t.get(Integer.class, Processor<Integer>.class);

    }

    public <T> Processor<T> get( Class<T> key, Class<Processor<T>> value ) {
        return value.cast(values.get(key));
    }

}
```

It creates a map of processors and exposes 'get' method. The issue I have is that this is not valid and javac complains:

```
Processor<Integer>.class
```

I ended up doing brute force cast:

```
Processor<T> processor = (Processor<T>)(values.get(key));
```

But it obviously gives me Unchecked cast warning.
How can I go around this warning? I wonder if the whole approach is not good and there is more elegant way to design this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you could change it to:

```
public <T> Processor<T> get(
        Class<T> key, Class<? extends Processor<T>> value) {
//                          ^^^^^^^^^
    return value.cast(values.get(key));
}
```

Which lets you do:

```
Processor<Integer> ap = t.get(Integer.class, AProcessor.class);
```

Or:

```
public <T, P extends Processor<T>> P get(
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        Class<T> key, Class<P> value) {
    return value.cast(values.get(key));
}
```

Which lets you do:

```
AProcessor ap = t.get(Integer.class, AProcessor.class);
```

These work because you have a subclass for each processor.

javac complains because a generic type like `Processor<Integer>` is a *type* but not a *class*. Only `Processor` is a *class*, so there is only a `Processor.class`.

Otherwise, you can suppress warnings:

```
public <T> Processor<T> get(Class<T> key) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final Processor<T> p = (Processor<T>) values.get(key);
    return p;
}
```

This unchecked cast design is fine for most cases but it breaks down with generic types. If you have e.g. a `Processor<List<String>>`, you can only retrieve it as a `Processor<List>`. This is because there's only a `List.class` which is a `Class<List>`.

In other words, suppose there's a:

```
class CProcessor extends Processor<List<String>> {
    public void process(List<String> foo) {}
}
```

```
t.values.put(List.class, new CProcessor());
// oops, we lost the type of the List
Processor<List> c1 = t.get(List.class);
// and this doesn't compile
Processor<List<String>> c2 = t.get(List.class);
```

And then suppose there's a:

```
class DProcessor extends Processor<List<Float>> {
    public void process(List<Float> foo) {}
}
```

```
// oops, we just replaced CProcessor
t.values.put(List.class, new DProcessor());
```

In that case, you can use something like Guava's [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) instead of `Class` which lets you have a `new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}` and a `new TypeToken<List<Float>>() {}`.

Comment: Thanks, i'm suppressing the warnings for now. The thing is i didn't want to know specific class of each processor in the calling class: AProcessor.class.

Comment: The unchecked way is fine as long as everyone is aware of the limitations. (Also see my edit where I've pointed out another.) And that if you suddenly get an unexpected `ClassCastException`, you know which parts of the code base to include in examination (putting and getting processors).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to get around the need for an unchecked cast in something like this, because the type of your internal `Map` is going to have to be broad enough to handle different processors. You are really doing run-time type checking here, and Java generics are a compile-time-only mechanism.

In a case like this, a cast is fine: you have full control over the objects going in to that map, so you can make sure it's correct. Use an annotation to suppress the compiler warnings if you need to.

You might want your Processor interface to have a `Class<T> getTargetClass()` so you can test at run time what class a Processor applies to. That would make it easier to do run-time validation of the Processors going in to your map to make sure they're correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I think you're trying to achieve through anonymous and semi-functional code:

```
// simple parametrized functional interface
interface Processor<T extends Number> {
    void process();
}
// definition of the actual process - "MyProcess" to avoid name clashes
abstract class MyProcess<T> implements Runnable {

    protected T t;
    MyProcess(T t) {
        this.t= t;
    }
}
// factory class to get Processor instances
class ProcessorFactory {
    static <T extends Number>Processor<?> getProcessor(final MyProcess<T> process) {
        return new Processor<T>() {
            @Override
            public void process() {
                process.run();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then, in a `main` method somewhere...

```
ProcessorFactory.getProcessor(new MyProcess<Long>(42l) {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("%s: %d%n", t.getClass().getSimpleName(), t);
    }
})
.process();
ProcessorFactory.getProcessor(new MyProcess<Integer>(42) {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("%s: %d%n", t.getClass().getSimpleName(), t);
    }
})
.process();
```

**Output**

```
Long: 42
Integer: 42
```

**Comments**

- This draft solution may resolve your issue by removing any need for pre-mapping your type parametrization
- It uses "anonymization" while extending `MyProcess`, and more debatably, while extending `Processor` in the factory

Comment: Thanks! This is quite different from my whole approach, i have to try to see how it fits into overall design. I'm not that good with generics so it takes a while to wrap my head around it lol

Comment: @a7d0rn you're welcome! I admit this is a little under-documented as is, I got lazy :) Hope it's useful to you.